# Using OR inside ternary operator

Tags: c#, if-statement, ternary-operator

I want to make following condition but its wrong. What can be done to make it correct?

```
row["Total Serviceable Offers"].ToString() == "a" || "b" ? "0" : "c";
```

Can we have || inside ternary condition?

Comment: Just don't...The long hand version will be much more readable

Comment: Agreed with @Liam. As soon as you throw a second condition in there, you're kinda defeating the purpose of using shorthand for simplicity.

Comment: @DangerZone I half agree, I feel as if a ternary is fine if you have two conditions represented as an `or`, but if you use an `else` with it then it loses its purpose

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre I guess I've really only ever used them with all parts (never left out the "else"). And I tend to only use them when the condition is short enough such that the entire statement remains on one line for concision. For example, if the line in the question were expanded to the correct code, likely it would wrap to the next line (with my font size anyway). That is what I meant. Not that you shouldn't ever do 2, just avoid using this unless it's actually providing the intended benefit. Your answer is fine, because you've simplified the whole string portion.

Comment: @DangerZone I may have worded that badly, all components are required, leaving the else out is a syntax error - I actually meant that having another ternary inside the else part is over the top :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string theRow = row["Total Serviceable Offers"].ToString();
(theRow == "a" || theRow == "b") ? "0" : "c";
```

Answer (score 4):

> Can we have `||` inside ternary condition?

Yes, you can. But in the way you did it the `||` us between
 `row["Total Serviceable Offers"].ToString() == "a"`, a Boolean expression, and `"b"`, a string expression. That is why your code does not compile.

You can change it to `Contains` or `Any` expression, or make a helper method if there is more comparisons than what your code snippet shows.

Here are several ways to rewrite your expression:

```
new[]{"a", "b"}.Contains(row["Total Serviceable Offers"].ToString()) ? "0" : "c";
new[]{"a", "b"}.Any(s => s == row["Total Serviceable Offers"].ToString()) ? "0" : "c";
IsAorB(row["Total Serviceable Offers"].ToString()) ? "0" : "c";

...

bool IsAorB(string s) {
    return s == "a" || s == "b";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran `int f = (g > 0 || h > 0) ? j : k;` in a test program and it did not error, so pretty much yes you can.

Just be careful with the logic, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for this syntax

```
(row["Total Serviceable Offers"].ToString() == "a" || row["Total Serviceable Offers"].ToString() == "b") ? "0" : "c";
```

But I would prefer the short approach with `Contains()`

```
new[]{"a","b"}.Contains(row["Total Serviceable Offers"].ToString()) ? "0" : "c";
```